# MongoDB sharding creatse only one chunk

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, cluster-computing, sharding

I created a mongodb cluster according to digitalocean's instructions. I sharded my database with the following command:

```
sh.shardCollection("database.Collection", {"userId": 1})
```

However, the collection is not split:

```
db.Collection.getShardDistribution()
Shard shard2 at shard2/82.X.X.X:27017
{
  data: '10.07MiB',
  docs: 14180,
  chunks: 1,
  'estimated data per chunk': '10.07MiB',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 14180
}
---
Totals
{
  data: '10.07MiB',
  docs: 14180,
  chunks: 1,
  'Shard shard2': [
    '100 % data',
    '100 % docs in cluster',
    '744B avg obj size on shard'
  ]
}
```

I use Parse and Ubuntu. Where is the mistake?

I have set up the servers several times, but each time only one chunk is created.

With the command

```
show dbs
```

I get the following output

```
database    24.84 GiB
```

Why are the sizes so different? I only have one collection.

The following command didn't change anything either

```
db.adminCommand( { flushRouterConfig: "database.Collection" } );
```

Answer (score 0):

The default chunk size is 128 MiByte (64 MiByte in MongoDB version 5.0 and earlier). Thus, you must have at least 129 MiByte of data in your collection.

See [Data Partitioning with Chunks](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/#range-size)

Comment: Okay, but actually every single file is 20MB. And when I display the database size with "show dbs" it says
db 24.84 GiB.

Comment: 24.8 GiByte for the entire database or the single collection you try to shard?

Comment: My database has only one collection.

Comment: Did you insert and delete the data? The output clearly states something different.

Comment: No. All files are in this collection and have not been deleted.

Comment: What do you get from `db.getSiblingDB('database').Collection.stats()`? Either you made a simple typo or you are in the wrong database (what is the output of `db.getName()`?) or you even connected to the wrong MongoDB instance.

Comment: I check the collection with command db.Collection.getShardDistribution(). The 12 last lines are: sharded: true, size: 10.072671890258789, count: 14180, numOrphanDocs: 0, storageSize: 2.1328125, totalIndexSize: 0.765625, totalSize: 2.8984375, indexSizes: { id: 0.578125, userId_1: 0.1875 }, avgObjSize: 744, ns: 'databse.Collection', nindexes: 2, scaleFactor: 1048576 –

Comment: db.getName() show me database

Comment: So, your data size is 2.1 MiByte which is way below the initial chunk size of 128 MiByte. Do you have a database named `db`? What is the exact output of `show dbs`? (edit your question for that information, rather than a comment)

Comment: Yes, it is the name of my database. I edited my post.

Comment: There should be more databases, e.g.  config or admin

Comment: it shows me following databases:
admin   224.00 KiB
config    4.54 MiB
database 24.84 GiB

Comment: And what is the output of `db.getSiblingDB('config').collections.find({}, { _id: 1 })` and `db.getSiblingDB('database').stats(1024 * 1024)`? (as edit in your question)