# MongoDB sharding cluster show wrong size

Tags: mongodb, parsing, cluster-computing, sharding

I created a mongodb cluster according to digitalocean's instructions. I sharded my database with the following command:

```
sh.shardCollection("database.Collection", {"userId": 1})
```

With the command

```
show dbs
```

I get the following output

```
database    24.84 GiB
```

With the command

```
db.Collection.getShardDistribution()
```

I get the following output

```
Shard shard2 at shard2/82.X.X.X:27017
{
  data: '10.07MiB',
  docs: 14180,
  chunks: 1,
  'estimated data per chunk': '10.07MiB',
  'estimated docs per chunk': 14180
}
---
Totals
{
  data: '10.07MiB',
  docs: 14180,
  chunks: 1,
  'Shard shard2': [
    '100 % data',
    '100 % docs in cluster',
    '744B avg obj size on shard'
  ]
}
```

Why are the sizes so different? I only have one collection.

The following command didn't change anything either

```
db.adminCommand( { flushRouterConfig: "databse.Collection" } );
```

Comment: Related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76810989/mongodb-sharding-creatse-only-one-chunk): What is the output of `db.getSiblingDB('database').Collection.stats(1024*1024)`?

Comment: The code is too long for stackoverflow, I uploaded it here https://codeshare.io/WdnegY

Comment: You need to show only the last 12 lines from `stats()`. Note, your command is `sh.shardCollection("database.Collection"` but you check `"databse.Collection"` - one `a` less!

Comment: I check the collection with command db.Collection.getShardDistribution(). The 12 last lines are:   sharded: true,
  size: 10.072671890258789,
  count: 14180,
  numOrphanDocs: 0,
  storageSize: 2.1328125,
  totalIndexSize: 0.765625,
  totalSize: 2.8984375,
  indexSizes: { _id_: 0.578125, userId_1: 0.1875 },
  avgObjSize: 744,
  ns: 'databse.Collection',
  nindexes: 2,
  scaleFactor: 1048576

Comment: Please put such additional information in the question instead of a comment. Anyway the typo is obvious